# How to make Rollover images in Texbox?

Tags: html, css

I have seen this site www.entireweb.com
I was wondering how we can make the "Magnyfying Lens" in search box roll over like that.

If you notice it has 3 images..

I know how to do 2 roll overs but where will i put the 3rd one..

Thanks

Please code it if your free :p

Comment: What mag lens? I don't see it in Chrome

Comment: thank god there's another search engine

Comment: Magnifying lens in the search box !

Comment: The magnifying glass isn't actually *in* the text field. It's just styled to **look** like it's part of the text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is 3 selectors to think about

**:hover**

**:active**

and then the default state of the link/button

you can see it in action here
http://www.jsfiddle.net/rpSgy/

just made an example with images

http://www.jsfiddle.net/ZATzF/

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.Any example ??

Comment: im trying to make one but jsfiddle isn't behaving give it a sec and it'll be up

Comment: your welcome, ps just made an example with images take a look

Answer (score 1):

the third is done on mousedown and on mouseup

```
$('#maglensid').mousedown(function(){
    //swap to pressed image
}).mouseup(function(){
    //swap to normal image
}).hover(function() {
    //swap to hover image
}, function() {
    //swap to normal image
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is their css, they are just moving a sprite image about using the css background property. A default position, a hover position and an active (i.e. clicked) position.

```
.web #front_logo, .web #search_form, .web #search {
   background-image: url("../skin_web_glare.png");
}

#search {
    background-position: -340px -70px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 44px;
    margin: 4px 0 0 7px;
    width: 43px;
}

#search:hover {
    background-position: -390px -70px;
}

#search:active, #search.active {
    background-position: -440px -70px;
}
```

So I don't think they are actually using any jquery/javascript just css (the way it should be :)).